# WYSIWYG editor generated by Wp_editor is disabled

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, ckeditor

Initial issue:

My client wanted an custom HTML rendering sidebar widget for their wordpress site. I created a simple one that allows them to choose the color (class switching) and gives them a textarea to put their HTML into. Now they have requested a basic WYSIWYG interface attached to it (CKEditor or TinyMCE) but I dont know how to add it to the textarea inside the widget code. Does anyone know how, have an example, or a place to see how it can work? Thanks!

EDIT (After use of wp_editor):

So I have my code to this point but the editor is disabled and not able to be used. Any ideas why?

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Enter your HTML</label>

    <?php 
    $settings = array(
        'wpautop' => true,
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => ',bold,italic,underline,|,link,unlink',

        ),
        'quicktags' => false
    );
    $bodyID = $this->get_field_id('body');
    $content = '';
    wp_editor($content, $bodyID, $settings );
    ?>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `wp_editor` function, your code will look something like this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

```
 <fieldset>

    <label> Your label for the text area </label>

    <?php 
    $settings = array(
        'wpautop' => true,
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,' .
                'bullist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter' .
                ',justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|' .
                ',spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv ',

        ),
        'quicktags' => false
    );
    wp_editor('initial content', 'id of textarea', $settings );
    ?>
    </fieldset>
```

**Note** that if you want to put the content in the WP database from front end you should use in addition `wp_insert_post` function and a `POST` varible as a link.

Comment: I added that code block above to my widget but it did not create a Toolset for it. Just a textarea.

Comment: Here is my form code:

`<p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('body'); ?>">Enter custom text/HTML: <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('body'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('body'); ?>"><?php echo  htmlspecialchars($body); ?></textarea></label></p>`

Comment: I think you should remove the textarea. the wp_editor function will create it for you. anyway, it will be good if you edit your post using this code so that maximum people of the community help you.

Comment: Sorry, the code block above is my original code I used to produce the current text area. When I added your code block under it, it just produced another textarea with no controls.

Comment: What I am asking you is to remove your original textarea code and put the wp_editor function. use the same ids. In other words, wp_editor first two parameters should be adjusted to your situation.

Comment: Ok, I apparently still have some things off but it's close:

`<fieldset>

    <label>Enter your HTML</label>

    <?php 
    $settings = array(
        'wpautop' => true,
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => ',bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,|,link,unlink',

        ),
        'quicktags' => false
    );
    wp_editor(htmlspecialchars($body), $this->get_field_id('body'), $settings );
    ?>
    </fieldset>`

Comment: The widget appears but is not editable/usable, and I want to remove 'Styles' and 'Align Full' and 'Paragraph' drop downs

Comment: you can customize the $settings variable so that your editor fit with your requirements, just read the codex page I gave you. In addition, the first parameter of wp_editor can be an empty string (If you want no intial content). I can say nothing about the second parameter in your case, you should find what is the way to put in it the id you need for your generated textarea'

Comment: what does $this->get_field_id('body'); returns?

Comment: and you should know that this is the built-in editor of wordpress, and you can customize it the way you like.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! The $this->get_field_id('body') is what the standard textarea uses for the id field so I thought I would just keep the same convention. I need the body to repopulate with any entered content from the user so I am using the same information that the textarea uses to repopulate from the database. I dont see any parameters where those last 3 are coming from. I only want bold, underline, italics, link/unlink, and possibly bullet list.

Comment: i Aagree with you, not so easy to remove the 'Styles' and 'Align Full' and 'Paragraph' drop downs from codex, it needs some research, I will come back here tomorrow to provide with what I found maybe I will ask on stackexchange. good luck

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to use wp_editor($content, $bodyID, $settings ); Setting the $content to the returned $body from the database and set $bodyID to the value of the $this->get_field_id('body'), the widget renders but I cannot add any text to the box, seems locked.

Comment: try to set $content to empty string. It is really weird your widget behaviour!!

Comment: Yep, set the content to '' and it still is disabled. This is odd :)

Comment: Still at the same point. About to readdress this issue in the next two days for the client. I still am failing to see what the issue is and not one has responded to me since you helped.